# Consult `kill -SIGUSR2` within the manual

Tags: kill

I learned a debugging tip using `kill -SIGUSR2`

it works but not defined in the manuals

```
me@alpha:~:
$ man kill |grep -i sigusr
me@alpha:~:
```

What' s the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a user-defined signal, so these are not part of a command but can be used by commands as they will be transformed into a value.  As such you will not find them in the manual for kill. Just like you wont find a variable like $USER but you could use it in the `kill -u $USER` (WARNING: this will kill any process that has your username connected).

You will find SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 in [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43).

> The  header shall define the following macros that are used to refer to the signals that occur in the system. Signals defined here begin with the letters SIG followed by an uppercase letter. The macros shall expand to positive integer constant expressions with type int and distinct values. So the signal names should be macros.